# Highcharts dual y-axis labeling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to have labels in both y-axis of this graph. I managed the one on the left (Million Tonnes) but I can't figure out the one on the left. Right now it says Value but it should say **Recycling Rate (%)**. The idea of course is that it displays in the way as Million Tonnes. In other words, the same alignment. TIA
[image: (%)]

You can see the code here:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var label = this.renderer.label("SOURCE: CEPI")
          .css({
            width: '600px',
            fontSize: '1em',
            color: '#414042'
          })
          .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'r': 2,
            'padding': -15
          })
          .add();
        label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
          align: 'center',
          x: 30, // offset
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y: 0 // offset
        }), null, 'spacingBox');
      }
    },
    marginBottom: 90
  },
  title: {
    text: 'European Recycling Rate of Paper for Recycling',
    style: {
      fontSize: '2.5em'
    }
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'CEPI Statistics - Status as of 2015'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickLength: 0
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  }, {
    opposite: true,
    linkedTo: 0
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    color: '#8cc640',
    name: 'Paper & Board Consumption',
    data: [64.801, 65.576, 65.863, 70.939, 70.937, 71.124, 76.629, 79.788, 82.228, 86.826, 83.878, 84.895, 86.673, 88.918, 89.903, 91.916, 93.165, 90.209, 80.996, 84.873, 83.496, 81.280, 80.161, 81.288, 82.484]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    color: '#6cbd56',
    name: 'Recycling inside Europe',
    data: [26.641, 27.781, 28.611, 31.823, 33.359, 34.597, 36.960, 38.906, 40.544, 43.174, 43.658, 44.800, 45.730, 47.641, 49.011, 50.731, 51.504, 50.184, 46.149, 49.800, 49.108, 48.420, 49.287, 49.511, 49.583]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    color: '#009347',
    name: 'Recycling Outside Europe',
    data: [-0.512, -1.038, -0.598, -0.662, -0.319, 0.358, 0.725, 1.109, 2.339, 1.779, 2.347, 2.436, 3.029, 4.655, 6.587, 7.306, 8.535, 9.853, 12.058, 8.371, 9.406, 9.446, 8.319, 8.561, 9.384]
  }, {
    name: 'Recycling Rate',
    color: '#2f7cba',
    data: [40.3, 40.8, 42.5, 43.9, 46.6, 49.1, 49.2, 50.2, 52.2, 51.8, 54.8, 55.6, 56.3, 58.8, 61.8, 63.1, 64.4, 66.6, 71.9, 68.5, 70.1, 71.2, 71.9, 71.4, 71.5],
    marker: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#2f7cba'
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put title for each axis

```
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Million Tonnes'
    }
  }, {
    opposite: true,
    linkedTo: 0,
  title: {
      text: 'Recycling Rate (%)'
    }
  }],
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var label = this.renderer.label("SOURCE: CEPI")
          .css({
            width: '600px',
            fontSize: '1em',
            color: '#414042'
          })
          .attr({
            'stroke': 'silver',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            'r': 2,
            'padding': -15
          })
          .add();
        label.align(Highcharts.extend(label.getBBox(), {
          align: 'center',
          x: 30, // offset
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y: 0 // offset
        }), null, 'spacingBox');
      }
    },
    marginBottom: 90
  },
  title: {
    text: 'European Recycling Rate of Paper for Recycling',
    style: {
      fontSize: '2.5em'
    }
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'CEPI Statistics - Status as of 2015'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickLength: 0
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Million Tonnes'
    }
  }, {
    opposite: true,
    linkedTo: 0,
  title: {
      text: 'Recycling Rate (%)'
    }
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    color: '#8cc640',
    name: 'Paper & Board Consumption',
    data: [64.801, 65.576, 65.863, 70.939, 70.937, 71.124, 76.629, 79.788, 82.228, 86.826, 83.878, 84.895, 86.673, 88.918, 89.903, 91.916, 93.165, 90.209, 80.996, 84.873, 83.496, 81.280, 80.161, 81.288, 82.484]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    color: '#6cbd56',
    name: 'Recycling inside Europe',
    data: [26.641, 27.781, 28.611, 31.823, 33.359, 34.597, 36.960, 38.906, 40.544, 43.174, 43.658, 44.800, 45.730, 47.641, 49.011, 50.731, 51.504, 50.184, 46.149, 49.800, 49.108, 48.420, 49.287, 49.511, 49.583]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    color: '#009347',
    name: 'Recycling Outside Europe',
    data: [-0.512, -1.038, -0.598, -0.662, -0.319, 0.358, 0.725, 1.109, 2.339, 1.779, 2.347, 2.436, 3.029, 4.655, 6.587, 7.306, 8.535, 9.853, 12.058, 8.371, 9.406, 9.446, 8.319, 8.561, 9.384]
  }, {
    name: 'Recycling Rate',
    color: '#2f7cba',
    data: [40.3, 40.8, 42.5, 43.9, 46.6, 49.1, 49.2, 50.2, 52.2, 51.8, 54.8, 55.6, 56.3, 58.8, 61.8, 63.1, 64.4, 66.6, 71.9, 68.5, 70.1, 71.2, 71.9, 71.4, 71.5],
    marker: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#2f7cba'
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```